# Mockito test coverage for new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(path)

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have all my beans in the context files which I use for the Mockito tests, to test my DAO's.

```
private static ApplicationContext getCtx() {
        synchronized (THREADMUTEX) {
            if (ctx == null) {
            try {
             String[] paths = { "classpath*:application-Context.xml",
                                   "classpath*:applicationContext-dao.xml" };
                ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(paths);
                System.out.println("context for laws  --> " + ctx);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }
        }
        return ctx;
    }
```

While running test I am getting below exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testataSource': Invocation of init method failed

How to mock `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(paths);`?

Comment: Use the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` jUnit runner and the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. Don't initialize the ApplicationContext yourself

Answer (score -1):

If you will mock `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springFiles)` you won't have Spring Context at all. If you don't need them then just run your tests without spring context and test your classes by instantiating them in code.

But if you need spring context then you shouldn't mock them, you should fix bean declaration and make it works.

Comment: Thanks Andriy for your inputs. I have updated the code snippets for better understanding, could you please have a look and suggest me as what needs to be done.